# MS SQL Server: Generate sequential data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In this example, I would like to insert data into a specified table from a view.
however, one of the field should be a calculated field that today's date; However each row should be incremented by 1 until all data from the other view have been inserted.

```
Insert INTO myTable SELECT a, b, c, GETDATE() AS d FROM MyView
```

The problem is: d must be today's date only in the first row.  The following row, it must be GETDATE()+1 etc until all values in MyView has been inserted into MyTable.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Having a utility table with integers from 0 to [some large integer] comes in ***really handy*** for situations like this.

Comment: @Conduit it would be good to show how you might use such a thing with reference to the OP's `MyView`

Comment: @Tim Lehner MS SQL 2008

Comment: @TimLehner working on it :)

Comment: @Conduit, thought of that in the beginning but as pointed out, it would bring out other considerations, MyView, not necessarily having the same number of rows as "That Table" being one...

Comment: Misread this, actually - since row number is the deciding factor the answer below will be the best I'm aware of.

Comment: @MichelBaradosa Precisely... no need to reinvent the wheel here. I'm guessing use of `ROW_NUMBER()` will outperform any wizardry I can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert INTO myTable
SELECT a, b, c, DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a,b,c)-1, GETDATE() ) AS d
FROM MyView
```